# Como criar uma macro do Excel para excluir linhas duplicadas

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Tem como alguém mostrar um exemplo de Macro em Excel que remova linhas duplicadas, porém comparando todas as células da mesma, ou selecionando quais comparar, exemplo

```
para linha_atual em todas_as_linhas faça

    para linha_de_comparacao em todas_as_linhas faça
        se todos as células da linha atual forem iguais as células da linha de comparação 
            remova a linha_atual
        fim se
    fim para
fim faça
```

Ou também o mesmo algorítimo á cima mas ao invés de comparar todas as colunas, comparar apenas  uma lista de colunas especificas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existem duas formas de resolver isso no Excel.

**A primeira é em simples**:
Usando o comando .removeduplicates do VBA do Excel

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:B8").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
```

**A segunda forma é mais difícil de entender e fazer**:
Utilize dois comandos for each e verifique se os valores dos objetos são iguais. Ex:

```
Dim linha1, linha2 As Object

    For Each linha1 In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan1").Range("A1:A8").Cells

        linha1.Activate

        For Each linha2 In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan1").Range(Selection.Offset(1, 0).Address & ":A8").Cells

            If linha1.Value = linha2.Value Then

                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan1").Range(linha2.Row & ":" & linha2.Row).Delete shift:=xlUp
                linha1.Activate

            End If

        Next linha2

    Next linha1
```

o que posso garantir é que mesmo a primeira forma de fazer seja mais simples, também é mais segura. Porque pode ser que no segundo formato de fazer o comando for each "salte" uma linha toda vez que praticar o comando .delete

Espero ter ajudado.

At.

Answer (score 3):

Uma outra forma de fazer esta exclusão seria com o laço for

```
Dim linha as double

Dim linha2 as double

Dim valor1 as string 'se for um texto por exemplo o valor a ser buscado

for linha = 2 to 999999 'Começando na linha 2 caso tenha um cabeçalho

   if (len(cells(linha,1)) < 1 then exit for

     colDaVariavel1 = "Inserir o valor da coluna que esta a variavel"

     'Se necessário entre com as colunas das variaveis a serem comparadas em variaveis diferentes e crie variavei como a valor1

    valor1 = cells(linha, colDaVariavel1)

    For linha2 = (linha + 1) to 999999

       if (len(cells(linha2,1)) < 1 then exit for

       if cells(linha2, colunaDaVariavel1) = valor1 and cells(linha2,  colunaDaVariavel2) = valor2 then

          cells(linha2).entireroll.delete

      end if

   next linha2

next linha
```

Answer (score 3):

O Modo mais Fácil --> Plan1.Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

Dessa Forma só é necessário instanciar a Coluna e se tem Cabeçalho ou não além de evitar sobrecarregamento da Workbook.

Answer (score 1):

estou aprendendo do VBA agora, e fiz desse jeito, talvez mais simples:

```
Dim TESTE As String
Dim TESTE2 As String
Dim LINHAS As String

LINHAS = 0
TESTE = 6
TESTE2 = 7

Range("a5").Select
Do While Plan1.Range("A" + CStr(TESTE)).Value <> ""

If Plan1.Range("t" + CStr(TESTE)).Value = Plan1.Range("t" + CStr(TESTE2)).Value Then

Plan1.Rows(TESTE2).Delete
LINHAS = LINHAS + 1
GoTo Pular
End If

TESTE = TESTE + 1
TESTE2 = TESTE2 + 1
Pular:
Loop

MsgBox "DUPLICADOS REMOVIDOS, FORAM REMOVIDAS " & LINHAS & " LINHAS!", vbInformation

End Sub
```