# Como apagar/deletar linhas repetidas comparando diferentes células?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

Quero saber como apagar uma linha que seja se repita ao longo da minha tabela. A imagem abaixo pode ajudar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Possíveis soluções:

1.

- Percorrer com a Macro do ficheiro `Excel1` esta passar os dado para
  o    ficheiro `Excel2`.
- Evitar que seja inserido no ficheiro `Excel2` a linha que contenha as mesmas infomações que já estejam inseridas.

Nessa solução eu pensei e criar uma Macro no ficheiro `Excel2`percorrendo todas as linhas e ir comparando as suas células. Porém não sei se é a maneira mais rápida.

2.

- Restringir que o ficheiro `Excel1` envie dados repetidos ao ficheiro `Excel2`

Obrigado!

Comment: Verifique esse link. Pode lhe ajudar:
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30819/como-criar-uma-macro-do-excel-para-excluir-linhas-duplicadas?rq=1