# Remover duplicatas baseando-se em valor de uma coluna

Tags: microsoft-excel, filtro, xls, planilha, libreoffice

Eu gostaria de saber como posso realizar o seguinte filtro:

[image: Antes da filtragem] ===> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, como remover as duplicadas na coluna "ação", mas deixando o registro de maior prioridade (no caso, '1' é a pessoa com maior prioridade e '8' a pessoa com menor prioridade).

Comment: Você utiliza Excel ou libreoffice?

Comment: No caso do exemplo, fiz em Excel, mas gostaria de entender uma solução para ambos, se possível.

Comment: Existem várias maneiras de comparar ou encontrar Strings. Uma [lista com alguns métodos de Localizar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272169/75104) pode ser encontrada na resposta do link. Depois cada dado localizado é comparado... Uma maneira rápida é utilizar o Autofiltro na coluna ação para uma ação e depois verificar o maior valor das células visíveis com uma WorksheetFunction.Min(). Pois o método nativo do Excel VBA `.RemoveDuplicate` não possui está função lógica de verificar a prioridade.

Comment: Veja [esta resposta também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30819/75104)

Answer (score 0):

Somente com macro, programando VBA. No LibreOffice Calc, sem usar macro, é possível fazer um filtro para uma linha, e não gerar todas as linhas. Seria gerada uma linha de cada vez.

[image: tabela a ser visualizada no LibreOffice Calc]

A tabela se resume às células A1:C9.

As outras células são fórmulas, exceto a célula C13, que deve ser alterada.

Agora vamos às fórmulas. O caractere "=" foi propositalmente retirado para a exibição da fórmula.

[image: fórmulas usadas no LibreOffice Calc]

Na célula B16, calcula-se a menor "Prioridade" da "Ação" escolhida.

Na célula A19, calcula-se o "Nome", referente à "Prioridade" e à "Ação".

A linha 19 seria o próprio filtro.